# symfony 2.0 bundles interworking

Tags: symfony, bundle, decoupling

I want to make an application based on a **main bundle** leaving the possibility for **other developers** to make **their own bundles to implement other features**.

Symfony 2.0 seems a good choice for that however I cannot figure out how to let the bundles to work together while preserving the decoupling.

In the MainBundle I will create a Controller which generates a **Users-List** like the one below:

```
 user1      edit   remove 
 user2      edit   remove
 ....
```

**How to let third-parties bundles to add their custom buttons to this list?**

For example an **AvatarBundle** may want to add a **button to upload of the Image**, a **SendEmailBundle** my want to add a **button to send an email** to the user and so on.

*How to preserve the bundle independency? How can I do that?*

Thanks a lot,
Massimo

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are only two ways of changing/adding functionality in provided bundles.

- Change the code
- Overriding the template/controller

In this case, the second seems far preferable.
The ways to override a template are:

- Define a new template in app/Resources
- Create a child bundle and override the template

If you also want the override controllers, the second way is the only way to go.
It's also my personal preference, since it's cleaner then putting specific stuff in the general app-folder, in my opinion.

Anyway, it is far better explained in the documentation of the FOSUserBundle:

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md

And ofcourse, this cookbook article:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html

Hope this helps,

Dieter

Comment: Well template or controller overriding rely on a "parent" bundle. In the case of the user-list, the MainBundle. However I see this technique  allows just one level of overriding... I mean there can be a second bundle who overrides the main bundle and adds the "avatar button" but what about the third bundle? How to add another custom button?

Answer (score 0):

If you know which parts of your bundle will be extended, you can use services (in the same way the tiwg bundle is using them for adding new templating filters/tags/helpers).
Your bundle will then 'scan' the services defined in the DIC (which have a defined tag) and then call them to get informations (button definitions in your case).